# C# Динамичный WebBrowser. Получить html

Tags: c#

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  WebBrowser reee = new WebBrowser();
  reee.Navigate("http://site.com");
  MessageBox.Show(reee.DocumentText);//вернёт пустоту
}
```

Надо подождать, пока загрузится страница, и сделать  `MessageBox.Show(reee.DocumentText)`.

P.S. БРАУЗЕР ВНЕ МЕТОДА ОБЪЯВЛЯТЬ НЕЛЬЗЯ!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зададим обработчик события `DocumentCompleted` используя лямбда-функцию.

```
WebBrowser reee = new WebBrowser();
reee.DocumentCompleted += (s1, e1) => MessageBox.Show(reee.DocumentText);
reee.Navigate("http://site.com");
```